# How to force a form error in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, html, jqgrid

Required fields and other restrictions will cause an error to appear in the add/edit form for jqgrid.

Here is the element html:

```
<tr id="FormError" style=""><td class="ui-state-error" colspan="2">State: Field is required</td></tr>
```

I would like to force an error based on other requirements that I do not see a way of stating in the grid configuration.

Specifically there are relational files that require certain values in the parent file to exist before they can be created.  So when a user is adding a record and attempts to create relation data before specifying the key values I want to stop them and issue an error.

Attached is an example of how it works normally.

Thank you and best regards.

[jqgrid form error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgbB7.png)

Answer (score 0):

In jqGrid  5.0.2 html tag FormError looks:

```
<div class="FormError ui-state-error" style="display:none;"></div>
```

So, use next:

```
$('.FormError').show().text("Error: bla bla");
```

Also you can look at errorTextFormat:

```
errorTextFormat: function(response) {
    return response.responseText;
}
```